# Do we need the [trojan] or [false-positive] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[trojan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trojan) wiki:

> A trojan is a malicious program which is injected to or poses as a
>   known application.

Tagged on 49 questions. Sometimes used in conjunction with the [antivirus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antivirus) tag with the premise, "Why is my program triggering a false positive?" For example:

- [How to correctly use atoi() and convert char to const char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706538/how-to-correctly-use-atoi-and-convert-char-to-const-char), actual question, hidden amongst the wall of text is: "It works well in g++ compiler on linux/GNU OS but when ever I compile it on a windows PC the antivirus always flags a Trojan Horse warning."
- [Compiled executable seen as Trojan threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317330/compiled-executable-seen-as-trojan-threat)
- [Why this C++ program is recognised as a Trojan? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256801/why-this-c-program-is-recognised-as-a-trojan)

Then there are some questions which have nothing to do with programming:

- [JS/Agent-NKG Trojan Warning in php website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596412/js-agent-nkg-trojan-warning-in-php-website)
- [Trojan on new USB Stick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275623/trojan-on-new-usb-stick)
- [Trojan[Downloader]/Win32.Banload in Borland C++ Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185472/trojandownloader-win32-banload-in-borland-c-compiler)

Presumably the ones about false positives are off-topic, yet [Malwarebytes gives trojan warning for basic C# “Hello World!” program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926360/malwarebytes-gives-trojan-warning-for-basic-c-sharp-hello-world-program) is an example of a popular question that has 85 upvotes.

In general, questions tagged [false-positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/false-positive) tend to be well-received. Wiki:

> False positive is the case where the positive result of a test doesn't
>   correspond to reality. It leads to wrong decision.

Some examples of the questions found on this tag:

- [Program Download - IE CHROME - “is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231581/program-download-ie-chrome-is-not-commonly-downloaded-and-could-be-dangerou)
- [Ways to keep my program away from being a virus false positive? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548621/ways-to-keep-my-program-away-from-being-a-virus-false-positive)
- [IE9 SmartScreen Warning, Despite Following All Recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313189/ie9-smartscreen-warning-despite-following-all-recommendations)
- [My C# app is getting flagged by anti-virus apps. How do I figure out why? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297722/my-c-sharp-app-is-getting-flagged-by-anti-virus-apps-how-do-i-figure-out-why)
- [What kind of non-lethal code usually triggers an antivirus? (false positives)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161291/what-kind-of-non-lethal-code-usually-triggers-an-antivirus-false-positives)

Though some of the questions contain code, it basically boils down to "how do I configure my anti-virus?" meaning they aren't actually programming questions.

I don't think anybody can be an expert in [false-positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/false-positive), which is only tagged on 83 questions, and is also used as a meta tag on some questions. Potentially [trojan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trojan) *could* be put to good use on questions regarding reverse engineering or something of a similar nature, but most of the questions on the tag appear to be garbage.

Comment: `false-positive` describes a type of incorrect result, it doesn't seem  important to the context and/or content of **both** the question and answer.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about interaction between custom code and antivirus are on-topic here, and they fall into two broad categories:

- Antivirus flagging the application as "malicious", where "malicious" could mean adware, spyware, worm, trojan, "potentially unwanted application", remote control backdoor, or whatever.
- Resource locking conflicts with antivirus scanning the same OS objects (typically files) that the application is trying to manipulate.  For example, deletion of a temporary datafile failing because the antivirus has a file handle open reading and scanning the file.

In the latter case, the asker rarely knows it is the antivirus at fault.  And backup utilities, etc could easily cause the same issue.

So let's just use [antivirus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/antivirus) for all flavors of the first, and one of the locking related tags for the second.